# When user login, Call to a member function prepare() on null in Laravel 8.x

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb, laravel-sanctum

I use Laravel Sanctum authentication system, and the user wants to log in, it says following error.

```
"message": "Call to a member function prepare() on null",
"exception": "Error",
"file":"C:\\wamp64\\www\\mylaravel\\mytest\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Connection.php", "line": 465
```

I use MongoDB as my database.

Versions i used:

- Laravel Version: 8.27.0
- PHP Version: 7.3.21

I try a lot of solutions but none of the solutions worked for me on Laravel 8.

Here is my User Model

```
namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\MustVerifyEmail;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
//use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\User as Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;
use DB;
use Laravel\Sanctum\HasApiTokens;
use \MongoDB\Operation\FindOneAndUpdate;

use Jenssegers\Mongodb\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;
use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\Access\Authorizable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Auth\Passwords\CanResetPassword;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\CanResetPassword as CanResetPasswordContract;

class User extends Eloquent implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use HasFactory, Notifiable, Authenticatable, Authorizable, HasApiTokens, CanResetPassword;

protected $connection = "mongodb";
protected $collection = "users";

//  public $timestamps = false;
 
 public function nextid()
{
    // ref is the counter - change it to whatever you want to increment
    $this->_id = self::getID();
}

public static function bootUseAutoIncrementID()
{
    static::creating(function ($model) {
        $model->sequencial_id = self::getID($model->getTable());
    });
}
public function getCasts()
{
    return $this->casts;
}

private static function getID()
{
    $seq = DB::connection('mongodb')->getCollection('counters')->findOneAndUpdate(
        ['_id' => '_id'],
        ['$inc' => ['seq' => 1]],
        ['new' => true, 'upsert' => true, 'returnDocument' => FindOneAndUpdate::RETURN_DOCUMENT_AFTER]
    );
    return $seq->seq;
}

/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'email',
    'password',
    'roles',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password',
    'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];
}
```

And this my controller

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use Validator;
use Auth;
use Arr;
use App\Models\User;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Register User
     * @param Request $request
     * @return Boolean  $result
     */


    public function register(Request $request)
     {
        $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
            "name" => "required",
            "email" => "required|email",
            "password" => "required|min:8"
        ]);
        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json([
                'status' => 400,
                'message' => "Bad Request"
            ],400);
        }

        $user = new User();
        $user->nextid();
        $user->name = $request->name;
        $user->email = $request->email;
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->password);
        $user->roles = "user";
        $user->save();

        return response()->json([
            'status' => 200,
            'message' => "user registerd"
        ],200);


 

}

 /**
 * Login User
 * @param Request $request
 * @return User  $user with token
 */

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
       $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),[
           "email" => "required|email",
           "password" => "required"
       ]);
       if($validator->fails()){
           return response()->json([
               'status' => 400,
               'message' => "Bad Request"
           ],400);
       }
       if(!Auth::attempt($request->only('email','password'))){
        return response()->json([
            'status' => 401,
            'message' => "Unauthorized"
        ],401);
       }

       $user = User::where("email",$request->email)->first();
       $token = $user->createToken('user token')->plainTextToken;

       Arr::add($user, 'token', $token);
       return response()->json($user);


    }
}
```